# post-hoc test on linear mixed effect model

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, post-hoc

I am fitting a linear mixed effect model to study the interaction of two independent variables, a covariate *time* and a factor *m* (levels "R" and "V"), on the outcome variable *var*. Data are grouped by the variable *id*, and I consider the intercept for each group as a random variable. In particular, I am interested in whether *var* assumes different values depending on the levels of *m* at different time points.

Here is how I am fitting the model:

```
> options( contrasts = c( factor = "contr.treatment",ordered = "contr.poly"))
> var.lm <- lme(var ~ m*time, random = ~1|id, data=dat, na.action=na.omit, method = "ML")
> summary(var.lm)

Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
Data: dat 
    AIC      BIC   logLik
    2091.779 2117.895 -1039.89

Random effects:
Formula: ~1 | id
         (Intercept) Residual
StdDev: 4.534834e-05 1.480997

Fixed effects: var ~ m * time 
                 Value  Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  2.5819962 0.10587243 570 24.387806  0.0000
mV          -0.8477854 0.14972621 570 -5.662238  0.0000
time         0.0103348 0.00490927 570  2.105150  0.0357
mV:time     -0.0161672 0.00694276 570 -2.328636  0.0202
 Correlation: 
        (Intr) mV     time  
mV      -0.707              
time    -0.560  0.396       
mV:time  0.396 -0.560 -0.707

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-1.6617004 -0.6537707 -0.2195518  0.4517715  3.9370134 

Number of Observations: 574
Number of Groups: 1
```

So there seems to be a significant interaction between *m* and *time*!

The data are normalized with respect to their mean at *time*=-1 for each level of *m*, such that the expected value $$E(var|time=-1,m=R) = E(var|time=-1,m=V) = 1$$

This is confirmed as follows:

```
> mean(dat[dat$time==-1 & dat$m=="R",]$var, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 1

> mean(dat[dat$time==-1 & dat$m=="V",]$var, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 1

> boxplot(var~time*m, data=dat[dat$time %in% c(-1),])
```

[image]

I therefore expect, by construction, that the post-hoc analysis to test the null hypothesis E(*var*|*time*=-1,*m*=R) - E(*var*|*time*=-1,*m*=V) = 0 is not statistical significant. However, it turns out to be, and I do not understand why. Most probably I am doing something wrong.

Since I am using dummy coding for the factor *m* with the level "R" as the reference value (meaning that mV=1 if m==V), the null hypothesis should translate into the formula mV-mV:time=0. Therefore, I perform this tests as follows:

```
> ph_conditional <- c("mV - mV:time  = 0");  
> var.ph <- glht(var.lm, linfct = ph_conditional);
> summary(var.ph)

Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Fit: lme.formula(fixed = var ~ m * time, data = dat, random = ~1 | 
id, method = "ML", na.action = na.omit)

Linear Hypotheses:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
mV - mV:time == 0  -0.8316     0.1532  -5.429 5.67e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

The null-hypothesis is rejected. There must be a problem and I cannot find it.

To make sure that my expectations are correct, I reduced the dataset to only the data at *time*=-1, and fit a model with no interactions. I expect the factor *mV* to be non statistically significant, meaning that the values of *var* at *time*=-1 and *m*=R are not statistically significantly different than those at *time*=-1 and *m*=V.

```
> dat_small <- dat[dat$time==-1,]
> options( contrasts = c( factor = "contr.treatment",ordered = "contr.poly"))
> var_small.lm <- lme(var ~ m, random = ~1|id, data=dat_small, na.action=na.omit, method = "ML")
> summary(var_small.lm)

Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
  Data: dat_small 
      AIC      BIC    logLik
  306.861 319.2114 -149.4305

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | id
         (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev: 1.242641e-05 0.6086403

Fixed effects: var ~ m 
            Value  Std.Error  DF t-value p-value
(Intercept)     1 0.06804805 160 14.6955       0
mV              0 0.09623447 160  0.0000       1
 Correlation: 
   (Intr)
mV -0.707

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-1.4611461 -0.7789445 -0.2552357  0.6026049  4.6896472 

Number of Observations: 162
Number of Groups: 1
```

As expected, mV is not significant. Therefore, I am doing some mistakes during the post-hoc analysis of the model with interaction. Any help is very much appreciated.

You can find the dataset as well as the code in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/y7kyl1e8qar0pgy/AABiLB-b3JURvCYhtEcNlkZma?dl=0). This is the dataset from which I have computed the results in this post, but it is not the complete dataset of my project. That's why I am using a random effect on the variable *id* even if in this reduced dataset there is only one group. I get very similar results by using the complete dataset. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might find it convenient to use the **lsmeans** package. `library(lsmeans); lsmeans(var.lm, pairwise ~ m)` will give you the predictions at the average value of `time` and compare them.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to compare at specific levels of *time*. In this case, I need to compare at *time* =-1. Also, I am not interested in comprehensive multiple comparisons; I need to do post-hoc tests at specific values of my independent variables to test my hypothesis.

Comment: Add `at = list(time = -1)` to the call. There is a lot of documentation in the package, including some vignettes, so I think you can find the information you need.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to take a look. However, I would like to understand why the analysis in the post does not give correct results. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'll try to look at it when I'm on PC instead of phone.

Comment: I tried lsmeans, but it gives a warning due to interactions and NaN. It says "NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions" and "In qt((1 - level)/adiv, df) : NaNs produced". Indeed, there are NaN in my dataset.

Comment: Edit: I removed all the NaN from the dataset, and it throws the same warning.

Comment: The NaN warning comes from the Tukey routine when you have extremely few d.f., not because if NAs in the dataset.

Comment: If you try `lsmeans(var.lm, pairwise ~ m|time, at = list(time = -1), adjust = "none")` it might work. But I wonder why so few df.

Comment: Not really, now it says: "Error in rep("", nrow(m)) : invalid 'times' argument
In addition: Warning message: In qt((1 - level)/adiv, df) : NaNs produced". Did you have a chance of looking at the code in the post?

Comment: I don't know. I'll look at the data

Comment: Both data and code are available; There is a link at the end if the main post. I was using the $var$ model.

Answer (score 1):

Just the error message doesn't tell the whole story:

```
> lsmeans(var.lm, pairwise ~ m | time, at = list(time = -1))
$lsmeans
time = -1:
 m   lsmean        SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 R 2.571661 0.1086969  0      NaN      NaN
 V 1.740043 0.1086969  0      NaN      NaN

Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in rep("", nrow(m)) : invalid 'times' argument In addition: Warning message:
In qt((1 - level)/adiv, df) : NaNs produced
```

From the output of the means, you *do* have results, and among them is the report that the degrees of freedom is zero. That make it impossible to do $t$ tests or confidence intervals. Looking further, I find:

```
> summary(dat$id)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      1       1       1       1       1       1
```

You have 0 d.f. because you have only one subject. I have no idea why `lme` didn't complain about this, but that's the problem.

If you really have only one subject, then you can fit a model to the data on that one subject, but your inferences apply only to that one subject:

```
> var.notmixed = lm(var ~ m*time, data = dat)
> lsmeans(var.notmixed, pairwise ~ m*time, at = list(time = -1))
$lsmeans
 m time   lsmean        SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 R   -1 2.571661 0.1086969 570 2.358166 2.785157
 V   -1 1.740043 0.1086969 570 1.526548 1.953539

Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast     estimate        SE  df t.ratio p.value
 R,-1 - V,-1 0.8316182 0.1537207 570    5.41  <.0001
```

It may be true that there is no difference in means of the data at time -1, but your model is fitting two straight lines with different slopes, and the times vary from -1 to +45. The lsmeans are based on predictions from the **model** at time -1. I emphasized model to make it clear that they are not predictions from the data. Here are the fitted lines:

```
> lsmip(var.notmixed, m ~ time, at = list(time=c(-1,45)))
```

[image]

Comment: Yet, the call to lsmeans provides weird results because, as said in the post, the data are normalized to the values at $time=-1$, therefore their means should be 1 both for $m=R$ and $m=V$. The call to lsmeans, on the contrary, gives 2.57 (for R) and 1.74 (for V). Why is that? Perhaps that is the reason why I get strange results also with the posthoc test goven in the main post?

Comment: I added more to the answer. I also suggest that you do `plot(var ~ time, col = 1 + as.numeric(m), data = dat)` and you'll understand why those fitted lines don't intersect at `time = -1`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, very useful! Plotting the data as you suggested made clear that the intercepts are different because the data at R are in average higher than those at V. I am confused now though. I am using the post-hoc at time=-1 as a sanity check, as I know as a fact that there should be no difference between R and V (by construction). If the lme (or lm) says that there is a difference, maybe I should not use this model. Indeed, from the responses, it is actually clear that var is non linear on time, so perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: If you have obvious nonlinearity, then clearly you should not use that model. You could try using polynomial terms in time, or transforming `var` and/or `time`.  In addition, I'm still worried about your having only one subject, but maybe that's just a partial dataset you provide.